# Do delayed Sidekiq Mailer methods execute when the job is processed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a typical ActionMailer with a method specifying an email delivery.

```
def some_email(user_id)
@user = User.find(user_id)

  if @user.eligible_for_email?
    mail(to: @user.email, from: "me@me.com", subject: "The Subject")
    @user.email_sent = Date.today
    @user.save
  end
end
```

I want to delay the sending of this using Sidekiq so I use:

```
Mailer.delay_for(2.days).some_email(user.id)
```

The eligible_for_email method:

```
def eligible_for_email?
    !unsubscribed? && email_sent.nil?
end
```

In the meantime, the user could have unsubscribed, which is why there is a method in the User model called `eligible_for_email?` which I can use to conditionally send the email - but obviously this condition needs to be tested just before the email is sent, not when the job is scheduled.

So the problem is that when I use Sidekiq to process this, the conditional logic doesn't seem to be run when the job is done.

Does Sidekiq work by executing the `some_email` method on runtime and then queuing the resulting email to be sent out two days later, thereby negating my conditional code?

Comment: The `some_email` method is not called until the scheduled time.  Is it possible that the problem is in `eligible_for_email?`?  Can you post the code for that method?

Comment: Sure. BTW it works fine when I call Mailer.some_email(user.id).deliver

Comment: Is `email_sent` getting set on the appropriate day or it getting set as soon as the mail is enqueued?  That will tell you for certain when the `some_email` method is getting called. Also, is `unsubscribed` a simple boolean attribute or is it a method?

Comment: Good point let me check - I'll change delay_for to 5.minutes; yes unsubscribed is a boolean that defaults to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is 100% correct and that's exactly what you want to do.

I'd guess you aren't restarting Sidekiq to pick up your code changes.  Sidekiq does not auto-reload changed code like Rails does.

Comment: Thanks for answering Mike :) Please forgive my ignorance - does Sidekiq cache the code to be run then?  So in 2 days when it does execute the method, it executes a copy that it keeps for itself?  Will try as you suggest as soon as I can.

Comment: @edralph did you solve your problem? I'm trying to achieve the same thing.